# Using collect in drools to get similar objects

Tags: drools, business-rules

I am trying to collect some objects in Drools, but I want to only collect objects which have the same attribute. To wit, imagine a TestData class:

```
public class TestData {
    int number;
    String name;
    //Getters, setters, rest of class
}
```

I want to use collect to get all TestDatas which have the same name. For the following data set, I want a rule which can collect the first two (both having the name 'Test1') and the second two ('Test2') as separate collections.

```
custom.package.TestData< number: 1, name:'Test1' >
custom.package.TestData< number: 2, name:'Test1' >
custom.package.TestData< number: 3, name:'Test2' >
custom.package.TestData< number: 4, name:'Test2' >
```

Something like

```
rule "Test Rule"
    when
        $matchingTestDatas : ArrayList( size > 1 ) from collect ( TestData( *magic* ) )
    then
        //Code
end
```

But obviously that won't work without the magic- it gets me an array of all the TestData entries with every name. I can use that as the basis for a rule, and do extended processing in the right hand side iterating over all the test data entries, but it feels like there should be something in drools which is smart enough to match this way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Presumably the "magic" is just:

```
TestData( name == 'Test1' )
```

or

```
TestData( name == 'Test2' )
```

... for each of the collections. But that seems too obvious. Am I missing something?

Based on the clarification from the OP in the comments on this answer, it would appear that a `Map` of collections is required, keyed from the name. To support this, `accumulate` is required, rather than `collect`.

```
$tests: HashMap()
    from accumulate( $test : TestData( name == $name ),
        init( HashMap tests = new HashMap(); ),
        action(
            if (tests.get($name) == null) tests.put($name, new ArrayList(); 
            tests.get($name).add($test);
        ),
        reverse(
            tests.get($name).remove($test); 
        ),
        result( tests )
    );
```

Comment: That would work if I knew in advance what the names were. But I don't. I want a rule which can grab all TestData with the same names, while not knowing in advance what the names are

Comment: Ah that makes more sense. I was confused by the fact that in your example you are collecting into a single `ArrayList`. If you want to create a collection of collections, where each is keyed from a name, then you should probably be using a `HashMap`. However, you will need to use `accumulate` instead of `collect`.

Comment: That did it - Accumulate got me what I wanted, though its a bit clunky.

Is there an easy way to have the rule fire only if the size of a list is 2 or more? I.e. if there's only one TestData with a given name, I don't want to bother processing it. I only want to process when two or more have the same name