# Drools: Firing a rule if a set of events has n distinct values for a property

Tags: drools, drools-fusion

Suppose we have an `Event` type that has 3 properties: `constraint`, `common`, and `distinct`. The goal is to write a rule in Drools that fires when a subset of `Event`s exists that meets the following criteria:

- `Event`s happened in the last *t* seconds; and
- `Event`s Have a previously **known** value for `constraint` property; and
- Share a previously **unknown** value for `common` property; and
- There are at least *n* different values for `distinct` property

If the rule fires, we need the set of participating events for further processing.

How do you advise we approach this problem?

Note 1: This question is somewhat similar to [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23505531/using-collect-in-drools-to-get-similar-objects), and Steve's answer there seems promising but is incomplete.

Note 2: Performance is of the essence. We have successfully developed rules that do this task, but they reduce the performance of the whole rule-base dramatically, and thus are unacceptable.

Edit 1: The current (poorly performing) solution looks like this:

```
rule ""
when
    $event : Event(constraint == CONSTANT_VALUE)
    $events : ArrayList() from collect(
            Event(constraint == CONSTANT_VALUE, 
            common == $event.common)
            over window:time( t ))
    $distinctVals : Set( size >= n ) from accumulate(Event($d : distinct) from $events, collectSet($d))
then
    // process $events
end
```

Comment: The first mistake ruining performance is that you latch onto `$event: Event` without making sure that this is not older than t seconds. This causes the rule to run for old events where there may or may not be a solution, and it will run repeatedly in cases there is a solution.

Comment: Another mistake is that you don't stop after collecting the ArrayList when this is shorter than n. Only if its size exceeds n it is possible to have at least one subset of n different distinct values.

Comment: The original code contains those constraints, but the performance gains coming from those is almost neglectable. I believe this ->"it will run repeatedly in cases there is a solution" and the repeated cartesian products the engine attempts to calculate create the performance problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Drools isn't meant to be used for computations that require repeated evaluations of a potentially big set of facts. In such a situation you'll have to offload the details to some Java code.

```
class Collector {
    String constraint;
    String common;
    List<Event> events = ...; // or Queue
    Map<String,List<Event>> dist2events = ...;
    int diversity;

    public void addEvent( Event e ){
        // 1. remove Event sets X from events older than t
        // 2. remove all members of X from dist2events,
        //    delete map elements where the value list is empty
        events.add( e );
        List<Event> ofDistinct = dist2events.get( e.getDistinct() );
        if( ofDistinct == null ){
            ofDistinct = new ArrayList<Event>(); 
            dist2events.put( ofDistinct );
        }
        ofDistinct.add( e );
        diversity = dist2events.keySet().size();
    }
}


rule createCollector
when
    Event( $constraint: constraint, $common: common )
    not Collector( constraint == constraint, common == $common )
then
    insert( new Collector( $constraint, $common ) );
end

rule addEvent
when
    $event: Event( $constraint: constraint, $common: common )
    $collector: Collector( constraint == constraint,
                           common == $common,
                           events not contains $event )
then
    modify( $collector ){ addEvent( $event ) }
end

rule MoreThan
when
    Collector( $constraint: constraint, $common: common,
               $events: events,
               diversity >= n )  // maybe only when n-1 to n?
then
    ... process $events
end
```

You'll have to decide whether you want this rule to fire only when the threshold n is exceeded or whenever the set changes while diversity is >= n.

You might want to add a rule to remove empty Collectors.

Comment: Thank you! This solution seems very promising and seemingly solves the performance issue.

Comment: On a side note, I happened to stumble upon your whitepaper, [Design Patterns in Production Systems](https://engage.redhat.com/forms/rule-design-patterns). Very insightful. I recommend it to every Drools newcomer. Cheers!

Comment: Since you've found the paper: there's a very similar pattern in there, IIRC something nicknamed "peephole".